# Convert flat array of persons into nested pedigree tree in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, tree, hierarchy

I'm trying to transform a flat list of persons into a structured tree of ancestry.

The source array of persons looks like this:

```
const list = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'John',
        akin: true,
        motherId: undefined,
        fatherId: undefined,
        partnerIds: [2]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Maria',
        akin: false,
        motherId: undefined,
        fatherId: undefined,
        partnerIds: [1]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Steven',
        akin: true,
        fatherId: 1,
        motherId: 2,
        partnerIds: [4, 5]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Stella',
        akin: false,
        motherId: undefined,
        fatherId: undefined,
        partnerIds: [3]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Laura',
        akin: false,
        motherId: undefined,
        fatherId: undefined,
        partnerIds: [3]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Solomon',
        akin: true,
        motherId: 4,
        fatherId: 3,
        partnerIds: []
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Henry',
        akin: true,
        fatherId: 3,
        motherId: 5,
        partnerIds: []
    }
]
```

It can contain n generations of people whose direct ancestors are defined by their respective fatherId and motherId. Unknown parents (oldest known ancestor, or related only by partnership) are simply undefined.
Partnerships are indicated by an array of partnerIds.

The expected output should look like this:

```
const pedigree = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'John',
        partnerships: [
            {
                partner: {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Maria',
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        name: 'Steven',
                        partnerships: [
                            {
                                partner: {
                                    id: 4,
                                    name: 'Stella',
                                },
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        id: 5,
                                        name: 'Solomon'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                partner: {
                                    id: 5,
                                    name: 'Laura',
                                },
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        id: 6,
                                        name: 'Henry',
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Visually the result would look like this:
[Visual pedigree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSOJu.png)
The desired output format is not intended for storing, but for easier visualization and processing for later rendering.

I tried to loop over the flat list, create a hashTable for referencing the single persons and then find partners and common children.
My issue is though that my approach only works for two generations, or one level of nesting, although I need it to be suitable for n generations.
I think I need some recursive function or way of starting to loop up from the bottom of ancestry somehow, but I can't figure out a smart way.

I'd be glad for any suggestions or tips!

---

**EDIT:**
This is what I've tried:

```
const createPedigree = (dataset) => {
    const hashTable = Object.create(null)
    dataset.forEach(
        (person) => (hashTable[person.id] = { ...person, partnerships: [] })
    )
    const dataTree = []
    dataset.forEach((person) => {
        if (person.akin) {
            if (person.partnerIds.length) {
                person.partnerIds.forEach((partnerId) => {
                    hashTable[person.id].partnerships.push({
                        partner: { ...dataset.find((p) => p.id === partnerId) },
                        children: []
                    })
                })
            }
        }
        dataTree.push(hashTable[person.id])
    })
    dataset.forEach((child) => {
        // fill partnerships with children
        if (child.fatherId && child.motherId) {
            if (
                hashTable[child.fatherId].akin &&
                hashTable[child.fatherId].partnerships.length
            ) {
                let mother = hashTable[child.fatherId].partnerships.find(
                    (partnership) => {
                        return partnership.partner.id === child.motherId
                    }
                )
                mother.children.push(child)
            } else if (hashTable[child.motherId].akin) {
                let father = hashTable[child.motherId].partnerships.find(
                    (partnership) => {
                        return partnership.partner.id === child.fatherId
                    }
                )
                father.children.push(child)
                
            }
        }
    })
    return dataTree
}
```

Comment: This is not a good way to store data. The way you had originally is a much better option. Searching through n nested objects to find a specific person would become a nightmare.

Comment: @about14sheep the desired output is not intended for storing the data, but for easier visualization

Comment: What would this look like if the parents of Stella were also present in the data? Would you duplicate Stella, so once that person is mentioned as partner, and another time as child?

Comment: @trincot Interesting question! 
I decided to not include parents of people who are not direct descendants of the kin for now. Mainly because the visualization would be tricky.
But as I am gathering this information aswell, I would be happy for every suggestion.

Comment: In that case you would probably go for a graph like data structure (instead of a strict tree-like structure). You would keep more properties in the output structure as well so they help with the visualization. The visualization would probably need to calculate a bit of extra metadata, positions etc and then repack/reposition things based on where you want things to display. Then it basically becomes a layouting problem.

Comment: How do you decide which of a pair of partners is primary?  That is, why do John and Steven get listed as parent nodes and Maria, Stella, and Laura are nested inside them?  Is it just because they are earlier in the the array?  Because they have lower-numbered ids?  Gender-bias?  Something else?

Comment: Each descendant can become the root of a node as he or she is akin and not related "only" by partnership. Although I see that the names in this example might seem like a male lineage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in the assumption that a general solution will involve some recursive calls (or a queue of candidates to expand until the queue is empty).

The output structure levels alternate between:

1. a person with partnerships
2. partnerships that contain a partner and children (each child is then again a 1.)

To make things simpler we can just model the 2 steps above with 2 separate functions. I chose the names `expandPerson` and `expandPartnership`.

```
const expandPerson = (personId, dataset) => {
    // we get the person from the dataset by their id
    const personData = dataset.find(p => p.id == personId)
    // we clone only the data that we want in the output
    const person = { id: personData.id, name: personData.name }

    // all partnerIds of this person need to become their parnerships
    // so we just map them to an "expanded partnership" (step 2.)
    person.partnerships = personData.partnerIds
       .map(partnerId => expandPartnership(partnerId, person.id, dataset))

    // we return the "expanded" person
    return person
}

const expandPartnership = (partner1Id, partner2Id, dataset) => {
    // we get the partner from the dataset by their id
    const partnerData = dataset.find(p => p.id == partner1Id)
    // we clone only the data that we want in the output
    const partner = { id: partnerData.id, name: partnerData.name }

    // all people in the dataset, whose parents are partner1Id
    // and pertner2Id are the children
    const children = dataset
      .filter(p => p.motherId == partner1Id && p.fatherId == partner2Id
        || p.motherId == partner2Id && p.fatherId == partner1Id)
      // we map each child as an "expanded person" again (back to step 1.)
      .map(p => expandPerson(p.id, dataset))

    // we return the "expanded" partnership
    return { partner, children }
}
```

In the code you then just call `const pedigree = expandPerson(1, list)`

If the root is not always `id: 1` just find the root `id` first

```
const rootId = list.find(p => p.akin && !p.fatherId && !p.motherId).id
const pedigree = expandPerson(rootId, list)
```

Note: you have a duplicate `id` (`id: 5`) in the provided input. You have to fix that.